# Validation failed: Password can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4.2, omniauth-twitter

I have an app, build on Rails 4.2 and tried to do twitter authentication, using `RailsCasts #241 Simple OmniAuth`.
But have this issue: `Validation failed: Password can't be blank!`
I searched answer everywhere, but did not find the solution!

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
    def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        create! do |user|
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.name = auth.info.name
        end
    end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def login
   end

   def create
       @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
       if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
           session[:user_id] = @user.id
           redirect_to root_path
       else
           redirect_to :back
       end
   end

   def create_session
       auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
       user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])    || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
       session[:user_id] = user.id
       redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Signed in!'
   end

   def logout
       reset_session
       redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get 'sessions/login'
  get 'sessions/logout'
  post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create'

  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create_session'
  post '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create_session'

  get 'registration' => 'users#new', as: 'registration'
```

**Solution**
After editing **user.rb** model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
    require 'securerandom'
    def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
       create! do |user|
          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.name = auth.info.name
          user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: try `allow_blank` instead of `allow_nil`

Comment: drop `minimum` validation for now, just try `allow_blank`

Comment: `You need to supply at least one validation`

Comment: could be an issue with has_password that it won't accept blank. Btw: A more updated approach is to have omniauth write to an identity table without a password, and then associate it with a user record.

Comment: and how can I do it?

Comment: I think it's prbm with `has_secure_password` try commenting it, and you can override the `has_secure_password`, Bcoz it is automatically adding `validates_presence_of :password_digest` this validation. So when specify `allow_blank` or `allow_null` it will not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative approach is to enter a random password on user creation. For example as shown in the [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) readme. So you could alter your code to this:

```
require 'securerandom'
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it addresses the underlying problem though and the solution below does not seem to apply to me but it is working for now!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's problem with

```
has_secure_password
```

try commenting it, and you can override the `has_secure_password` Or

```
has_secure_password(validations: false)
```

This is happening as it automatically adds

```
validates_presence_of :password_digest
```

So when specify allow_blank or allow_null it will not work